# Notepad++ highlighting numbers if line begins with a number and ends with a comma

Tags: syntax, notepad++

I'm trying to make custom syntax highlights, and I'm not sure about a few things.

`#stuff 1`

If a line begins with a hashtag, how do I make the whole line a specific color?

`1234567890,`

If a line begins with a number (is looking at each digit separately possible also?) and ends with a comma, how to I make each digit a specific color, such as 1 red, 2 blue, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can even set a different color for each digit, as there aren't infinite different options in the notepad++ UDL editor. But the comments should not be too hard. Let me explain:

*First set 'open' to '#' or whatever you want to start your comment line with.*
[image: First set 'open' to '#' or whatever you want to start your comment line with.]

Next, *press 'Styler'. Here you can set your text colors. I have chosen a grey background.*

[image: Then, press 'Styler' and set your style settings.]